# Navmesh bake does not recognize floor at diagonal position

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I made a 3D game with square floors which are completely fit into grid. Square floors are navigatable so when I bake navmesh, floors should be baked as navigatable path.

However, navmesh works only under certain condition, (floor.transform.position.x == 0 || floor.transform.position.z == 0).

As you can see from picture, floor 2 and 3 satisfy that condition so are baked well, but floor 1 is not baked at all since it does not satisfy the condition.

[image]

I don't know how to fix this. Is there any way to make navmesh bake all the floors well?

Comment: Are you sure all squares are setup correctly, normally navmesh is very accurate,

Comment: I checked several times. Floors are positioned at accurate place and those floors are from same prefab. I made a new project with default unity cube and navmesh, yet same problem occurred.

Comment: I feel for you, if you would be prepared, could you extract off the level from your game and allow us to download it from somewhere? as I would guess then that the navmesh is applied it just doesnt look like it